# Check if a device has a lock method configured via React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, keyguard

### Problem

We have to check whether a mobile phone / tablet has any locking functionality (PIN, Pattern, Biometrics, ...) enabled. If nothing was set, then the app shouldn't run.

Is there any way to do this via *React Native*? I have found - on Android - a [Keyguard Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager#isKeyguardLocked()), which seems to include this functionality, but couldn't find anything in the *React Native* docs about it.

So I fear my only option is to implement this myself via native modules? And is there even something similar like this on *iOS*?

Comment: have you checked this?
https://infinitbility.com/how-to-detect-screen-lock-set-or-not-in-react-native/

Comment: No, haven't seen it, but it looks promising. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following package
[device-info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info)

and use isPinOrFingerprintSet() method.
I'm not sure, but that's what I read!